# How to get duration of webm video file when duration is not explicitly defined

Tags: ffmpeg, webm, ffprobe

I have a segment of a webm file with an incomplete header, I want to cut this segment down to 10 seconds by trimming x seconds off the front of the file, however I am unable to use the `-sseof` tag because the end of the file isn't defined. I have discovered that if I ask ffmpeg to pull out the audio or video from the file it responds with some data long the lines of `size=     212kB time=00:00:13.32 bitrate= 130.2kbits/s speed=1.79e+03x     video:0kB audio:210kB subtitle:0kB other streams:0kB global headers:0kB muxing overhead: 0.991311%` Showing that there is 13.32 seconds of data in the file, however if I use ffprobe for the file length it replies with `N/A`. Is there a way to get that 13.32 value by itself without encoding the webm file?

Answer (score 2):

Run

`ffprobe -v 0 -hide_banner -of compact=p=0:nk=1 -show_entries packet=pts_time -read_intervals 99999%+#1000 input.webm | tail -1`

Assuming the file isn't longer than 99999 seconds, this will print the timestamp of the last media packet in the file.